# Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization, version- 2013.3.1316.45 is not supporting

Tags: c#-4.0, telerik, wpf-controls

I am using telerik RadTreeMap control. It is showing error when we use DLL Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization, version- 2013.3.1316.45 is not supporting. when I use version - 2013.3.1316.40 then it work fine. But all over in our application we already used the DLL of version 2013.3.1316.45 and we cant use the old version DLL 2013.3.1316.40. So how we can use the DLL version 2013.3.1316.45 In RadTreeMap application, please give the solution as early as possible.